# Integrate Worklight project in existing IOS project

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, integration

I have to integrate a Worklight project into my existing IOS project (Objective-C)
I have googled but i have not found a clear "guide" on how to perform this integration.
Could you drive me in the right way of integrating this project? The idea is to have a button in my IOS project that open a WebView that loads the pages (HTML5 and javascript with AngularJS and Jquery) contained into the Worklight project.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There is no guide for this approach, as I don't think it is sustainable.

In Worklight you currently have two approaches:

1. A native application to which you add the Worklight Native iOS SDK, allowing you to implement security features, invoke adapters and use various other features
2. A Hybrid application to which you can add native functionality (via Cordova or otherwise), and use the entire set of features provided by Worklight

It is important to note that a Hybrid application *is* a native application. It is a fully actual real native app. It is a native shell that calls a webview (provided by Cordova) into which the Worklight JS framework and the application web resources are loaded, and thus you see your web app. A Hybrid application allows you to mix & match web and native in one.

So what I am saying is that you can't take an existing iOS app and transplant it into another existing iOS app.

It sounds to me like what you are essentially trying to do, is what a Hybrid app is. A native app that displays web content...

So:

1. This is not an approach Worklight *officially* supports. By doing this, you are on your own
2. You could maybe take the guts of a Hybrid app's iOS environment (myapp\iphone\native) - its classes and resources and add them into your existing app and load the main class which theoretically, or at least the wanted effect, will load the Cordova webview. But I give this low chances of success...